# Mongodb: failed to connect to server on first connect

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I get the following error:

```
Warning { MongoError: failed to connect to server [mongodb:27017] on first connect
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/Users/michaelks/Desktop/users/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:325:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/michaelks/Desktop/users/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:270:12)
    at Connection.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/michaelks/Desktop/users/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:173:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at connectErrorNT (net.js:1025:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [mongodb:27017] on first connect' }
```

Even though I get this in the terminal window where I run Mongo:

```
2016-12-25T03:45:23.715+0100 I NETWORK [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58868 #8 (8 connections now open)
```

It kinda looks like there is a connection..

I've tried both

```
$ mongod
```

and

```
$ brew services start mongo
```

This is my test_helper.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb:localhost/users_test');
mongoose.connection
 .once('open', () => console.log('Good to go!'))
 .on('error', (error) => {
 console.warn('Warning', error);
 });
```

I have not specifically made the db "users_test" as I am under the impression that mongoose or mongo or both will do this on the fly.

I've tried both "localhost" and "127.0.0.1​".
I'm on OSX 10.11.5
I'm running Node 7.3.0 and Mongo 3.2.9

What am I doing wrong? How do I figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Check IP address of your system using command ipconfig/ifconfig. And then check in nodejs console error if it is using same IP address to make connection with mongodb.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[To connect](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) to `mongodb` with `mongoose`, you can use :

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/users_test');
```

or

```
mongoose.connect('localhost/users_test');
```

or

```
mongoose.connect('localhost','users_test');
```

But not `mongoose.connect('mongodb:localhost/users_test');`, it doesnt match the right hostname (`mongodb` instead of `localhost`)

Answer (score 30):

> Adding one more answer as the solution is from different contexts:

## MongoDb Atlas problem solution

I connected to MongoDB Atlas and whitelisted my machine's IP by following the below steps:

- Go to the security tab

[image: the security tab]

- Go to the network access tab under the security tab

[image: network access tab under security tab]

- Go to the IP whitelist tab

[image: IP whitelist tab]

- Enter the [IP address of your machine](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20is%20my%20ip)

---

Answer (score 13):

I was getting same error while I tried to connect mlab db that is because my organization network has some restriction, I switched to mobile hotspot and it worked.

Comment: This is might be a little-known answer but it saved me. Thank you

Comment: This saved me as well, thx mate. Interestingly, my organization network blocks mongodb but not postgresql

Comment: Thanks! Tried accessing mine using library hotspot and it wasn't working.

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this issue serval times, and  here is some `troubleshooting list`

1. make sure `database path` is `exist`, the default path in windows in `C:\data\db`
2. make sure `mongo is running`, to run it go to `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin` and run the following:

   1. `mongod.exe`
   2. `mongo.exe`
3. make sure that your `connection string is correct` like `mongodb://localhost/database-name`

Comment: mongodb://localhost/database-name not mongdb://localhost/database-name

Answer (score 7):

if it is cluster MongoDB then you need to add your current IP to the cluster, to add your current IP address you need to complete few steps below-

```
step 1- go to login page of Mongodb and login with valid credential - https://cloud.mongodb.com/user#/atlas/login
step 2- CLick Network Access from left sidebar under Security Section
Step 3 - Click Add IP Address
Step 4 - Click Add Current IP Address or Allow Connection From Any Where
now try to connect - npm start
```

[image]

and for Local MongoDB use mongo String like 
   "mongodb+srv://username:pass%40ord@clastername-blqnk.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

password must be encoded like example string

Comment: In my case, my IP address was not added. So it works for me.

Answer (score 4):

While connected to a wifi network, `mongodb://localhost/db_name`  worked as expected.

When I wasn't connected to any wifi network, this couldn't work. Instead I used,
`mongodb://127.0.0.1/db_name` and it worked.

Probably a problem to do with ip configurations.

Answer (score 3):

In case of remote db in cloud such as ATLAS, you should create whitelist entry 0.0.0.0/0. This allows you to access your cluster ATLAS from any IP address.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For me,issue was mongo was not running.So first i started "mongod" command in the console.And later in another console tab I have run "mongo". Now the connection is successful.
Now run your app your problem should be solved.

Answer (score 2):

I was running mongod in a PowerShell instance. I was not getting any output in the powershell console from mongod. I clicked on the PowerShell instance where mongod was running, hit enter and and execution resumed. I am not sure what caused the execution to halt, but I can connect to this instance of mongo immediately now.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to connect mlab with my company wifi connection and it was giving this error. But when I switched to personal network it worked and got connected.

Answer (score 1):

## Local MongoDb problem solution

solve it by following the below steps:

Changed

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/local
```

to

```
localhost/local
```

And the error gone

Comment: Mongodb default port is 27017. I think you had a small typo

Comment: @BertrandMartel Thanks for highlighting this. Not sure as to how I missed your comment.

Answer (score 1):

If the mongo instance is build on the cloud.mongodb.com this error appears when the instance can work only from known IP addresses set in the IP whitelist pool when the instance was configured.

So from the mongo dashboard need to be set the current IP address on the IP whitelist from network access menu on the left.

BR,

Answer (score 1):

I connected to a VPN and it worked. I was using school's WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 simple reasons for this other than configuration issue.

1. If you are connected to your organization/institute's VPN, there might be restrictions with connections.
2. You are not connecting from a whitelisted "IP"

To add a whitelisted IP, login to MongoDB Atlas, go to **Security** -> **Network Access** -> **Add IP Address**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/on8q9.png)

Then add your current IP in **'Access List Entry'** field

Comment: The answer contains the solutions already covered by the previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I restarted the Mac and was working again :)

Answer (score -2):

I tried all the method above.

- Allowed access from any db,
- Verified correct credentials of connection string,
- Created another user,

Nothing of those worked for me.

Finally, I created a new DB and switched to it.  everything was fine.
Luckily, it wasn't so important DB (for self education purpose) so the damage wasn't so big.

Comment: Your solution might be suitable for you personally, but it does not demonstrate a general solution as most probably the question poster can't simply do what you did.