# failed to connect to server on first connect. But sometimes it working after restat internet connection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, postman

What to do about this error?

> Server Running on port 5000 { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to
>   server [ds231242.mlab.com:31242] on first connect [MongoNetworkError:
>   getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ds231242.mlab.com ds231242.mlab.com:31242]
>       at Pool. (C:\MERNapps\TestMERN14\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:564:11)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at Connection. (C:\MERNapps\TestMERN14\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:316:12)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
>       at Connection.emit (events.js:214:7)
>       at Socket. (C:\MERNapps\TestMERN14\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:245:50)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)   name: 'MongoNetworkError',   errorLabels: [
>   'TransientTransactionError' ],   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
>   }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongodb: failed to connect to server on first connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318354/mongodb-failed-to-connect-to-server-on-first-connect)

Comment: after reset port... it will fix.