# Unable to connect MongoDB in Node JS application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, web

My application was running just fine and was connected to mongoDB while developing a simple node js application. But suddenly it started showing this error. Here is a snap of the console:

[image]

Here is my file providing mongoURI, and it was working just fine before the error:

```
module.exports = {
  mongoURI:
    "mongodb+srv://glorious:glorious@cluster0-to57n.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
};
```

Here is my server.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

// DB Config
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
  .connect(db)
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hello World"));

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

And here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "devconnector",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A social network for developers",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "Utkarsh Shrivastava",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "gravatar": "^1.8.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.13",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "validator": "^12.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid "current URL string parser is deprecated" warning by setting useNewUrlParser to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50448272/avoid-current-url-string-parser-is-deprecated-warning-by-setting-usenewurlpars) And they have documented usual deprecation warnings [Mongoose deprecations](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html)

Comment: @ambianBeing directly after the warning there's an ECONNRESET, which indicates that the server is not reachable at that location ...

Comment: Are you able to connect to the cluster instance directly via shell?? `mongo --host mongodb+srv://glorious:glorious@cluster0-to57n.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

Answer (score 1):

[**`useNewUrlParser`** doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#the-usenewurlparser-option):

> **The `useNewUrlParser` Option**
>
> By default, `mongoose.connect()` will print out the below warning:
>
> ```
> DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will
> be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option {
> useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
> ```
>
> The MongoDB Node.js driver rewrote the tool it uses to parse MongoDB connection strings. Because this is such a big change, they put the new connection string parser behind a flag. To turn on this option, pass the `useNewUrlParser` option to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()`.
>
> ```
> mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
> mongoose.createConnection(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
> ```
>
> You can also set the global `useNewUrlParser` option to turn on `useNewUrlParser` for every connection by default.
>
> ```
> // Optional. Use this if you create a lot of connections and don't
> want // to copy/paste `{ useNewUrlParser: true }`.
> mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
> ```
>
> To test your app with `{useNewUrlParser: true }`, you only need to check whether your app successfully connects. Once Mongoose has successfully connected, the URL parser is no longer important. If you can't connect with `{ useNewUrlParser: true }`, please open an issue on GitHub.

[**`useUnifiedTopology`** doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#useunifiedtopology):

> **`useUnifiedTopology`**
>
> By default, `mongoose.connect()` will print out the below warning:
>
> ```
> DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is
> deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new
> Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option {
> useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
> ```
>
> Mongoose 5.7 uses MongoDB driver 3.3.x, which introduced a significant refactor of how it handles monitoring all the servers in a replica set or
>   sharded cluster. In MongoDB parlance, this is known as server
>   discovery and monitoring.
>
> To opt in to using the new topology engine, use the below line:
>
> ```
> mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);
> ```
>
> If you find any unexpected
>   behavior, please open up an issue on GitHub.

So you need to pass both options to `mongoose.connect`:

```
// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
  .connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  ...
```

Comment: This didnt solve the problem, it gave: MongoTimeoutError

Comment: maybe you have to follow these steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/57266236/11129751

Answer (score 0):

your `server.js` file

```js
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const app = express();
// connect Database
connectDB();
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('API Running...'));
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Started On Port ${PORT}`));
```

`db.js` file under `config` folder

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('config');
const db = config.get('mongoURI');

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(db, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
    console.log('MongoDB Connected !!');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    // Exit process
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

`default.json` under config folder

```js
{
  "mongoURI": mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[database][?options]]
}
```

you can check more on 
[Connection String URI Format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) for `default.json`

Answer (score -1):

You are missing URL PARSER.
Just modify your code to

```
...rest of the code

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
  .connect(db, {newUrlParser: true})
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

...rest of the code
```

Or you can also set it globally using

```
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
```

Read more about it here
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html

Answer (score -1):

I have Just Worked with Mondo DB.
This code may helps

> add {useNewUrlParser:true} while connecting to MongoDb.see [Mongo DB deprecations](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html)

your server.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

// DB Config
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
  .connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hello World"));

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

Hope this work fine, and will connect you mongo db.