# Inconsistent connection errors on connecting to mongodb atlas from google cloud function

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-functions, mongodb-atlas

I have multiple ETL jobs running on google cloud function each of which is connecting to mongodb cluster on Atlas and querying data.

There are multiple instances of below error but not consitent

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [prod-prepare-shard-00-02-g7pxf.gcp.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect
```

I have a setup VPC peering with Cloud NAT and all of my functions use the NAT.

If I run the function again then there is no error.

What could be causing these connectivity issues from cloud function to atlas?

Comment: About the error you are getting I found a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318354/mongodb-failed-to-connect-to-server-on-first-connect) where they got the same error and part of the issue was related to the MongoDB IP Whitelist, also in this [Medium article](https://medium.com/harvested-financial-engineering/vpc-network-peering-gcp-and-mongodb-8dcd39a65fc4#:~:text=Whitelisting%20Your%20New%20Static%20IP%20in%20MongoDB) one of the steps is whitelisting the IP from the Cloud NAT. Could you please confirm if it is your case?

Comment: I have whitelisted the IP address and we can see the same working subsequently. This error is not consistent.

Comment: Could you please confirm if the same instances that are getting the error aren't able to connect at all or it is random and the same instance that get the error then is able to connect. These errors started appearing suddenly or they were since the beginning? If this started suddenly have you changed something recently?